# Disadvantages of train-test split

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science, cross-validation

"Train/test split does have its dangers — what if the split we make isn’t random? What if one subset of our data has only people from a certain state, employees with a certain income level but not other income levels, only women or only people at a certain age? (imagine a file ordered by one of these). This will result in overfitting, even though we’re trying to avoid it! This is where cross validation comes in." The above is most of the blogs mentioned about which I don't understand that. I think the disadvantages is not overfitting but underfitting. When we split the data , assume State A and B become the training dataset and try to predict the State C which is completely different than the training data that will lead to underfitting. Can someone fill me in why most of the blogs state 'test-split' lead to overfitting.

Comment: In your example model will overfit to State A and B, and therefore will not be able to predict State C. When the training data does not provide a representative sample you can infer incorrect assumptions about the population.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So when most of the blog mentions and focus too much about overfitting as the disadvantage of 'train-test' split , they just mainly point out the model will overfit to State A and B ?

Comment: Imagine you have no selection bias. In that case, when you overfit even a healthy set, you will still make the model biased towards your train set. Here, you have a starting biased training set at all, therefore even a moderate fitting will mimick the results of overfitting. (added to my answer)

Comment: When your training set is biased, you will make a model which fits the training set well but doesn't generalise to the population, hence overfitting. The problem is that you have inferred too much about the data, not too little as would be implied in the case of underfitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more correct to talk about [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias), which your question describes.

Selection bias can not really tie to overfitting, but to fitting a biased set, therefore the model will be unable to generalize/predict correctly.

In other words, whether "fitting" or "overfitting" applies to a biased train set, that is still wrong.

The semantic strain on the "over" prefix is just that. It implies bias.

Imagine you have no selection bias. In that case, when you overfit even a healthy set, by definition of overfitting, you will still make the model biased towards your train set.

Here, your starting training set is already biased. So any fitting, even "correct fitting", will be biased, just like it happens in overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

In fact train/test split does have some randomness. See below with sci-kit learn `train_test_split`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_set, test_set = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Here, in order to have some initial intuition, you may change the random_state value to some random integer and train the model multiple times to see if you could get a comparable test accuracies in each run. If the dataset is small (in order of 100s) the test accuracies may differ significantly. But when you have a larger dataset (in order of 10000s) the test accuracies become more or less similar as the train set would include at least some examples from all samples.

Of course, cross validation is performed to minimize the effect of overfitting and to make the results more generalized. But with too large datasets, it would be really expensive to do cross validation.

Answer (score 0):

The "train_test_split" function will not necessarily be biased if you do it only once on a data set. What I mean is that by selecting a value for "random_state" feature of the function, you can make different groups of train and test data sets. 
Imagine you have a data set, and after applying the train_test_split and training your model, you get low accuracy score on your test data. 
If you alter the random_state value and retrain your model, you will get a different accuracy score on your data set. 
Consequently, you can essentially be tempted to find the best value for random_state feature to train your model in a way that will have best accuracy. Well, guess what?, you have just introduced bias to your model. So you have found a train set which could train your model in such way that would work the best on the test set. 
However, when we use something such as KFold cross Validation, we break down the data set into five or ten (depending on size) groups of train and test data set. Every time we train the model, we can see a different score. The average of all the scores will probably be something more realistic for the model, when trained on the whole data set. It would look like something like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 
kfold = KFold(5, True, 1)
R_2 = []
  for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(X):

     X_train, X_test = X.loc[train_index], X.loc[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = y.loc[train_index], y.loc[test_index]
     Model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

     r2 = metrics.r2_score(y_test, Model.predict(X_test))
     R_2.append(r2)

  R_2mean = np.mean(R_2)
```